# Django queryset Product model and Product_images model, TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: django, django-templates

I am developing an ecommerce website with Django. I had Product and Product_images models as below:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='products')
    same_product = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='same_products', blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_categories')
    who_like = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='liked_products', blank=True)
   
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField('Slug', max_length=110, unique = True)
    sku = models.CharField('SKU', max_length=50, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField('Description', null=True, blank=True)
    sale_count = models.IntegerField('Sale Count', default=0)
    is_new = models.BooleanField('is_new', default=True)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField('is_featured', default=False)
    is_discount = models.BooleanField('is_discount', default=False)
    price = models.DecimalField('Price', max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    discount_value = models.IntegerField('Discount Value', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
class Product_images(models.Model):
    # relations
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')

    # informations
    image = models.ImageField('Image', upload_to='media/product_images')
    is_main = models.BooleanField('Main Image', default=False) 
    is_second_main = models.BooleanField('Second Main Image', default=False) 

    # moderations
    status = models.BooleanField('Status', default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'image'
        verbose_name = 'Image'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Images'
        ordering = ('created_at',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.image}'
```

In my Product_images model I store several images for one Product, in Product_images model I wrote
boolean fields with names **is_main** and **is_second_main**. In my template I want to get these images, in my terminal (interactive shell) when I write **single_product.images.get(is_main=True).image.url** can get image url, but in template I can't get image, but get an error as below:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '(is_main=True).image.url' from 'product.images.get(is_main=True).image.url'
```

Below is my view and template:

```
def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()

    context = {
        'products': products
    }

    return render(request, 'index/index.html', context)
```

```
{% for product in products %}
<div class="front">
   <a href="product-page(no-sidebar).html">
      <img src="{{ product.images.get(is_main=True).image.url }}" class="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img" alt="">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="back">
   <a href="product-page(no-sidebar).html">
      <img src="{{ product.images.get(is_main=True).image.url }}" class="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img" alt="">
   </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Please, help me with this problem and properly display these images, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve this problem, maybe it is not the best way, but work.

```
{% for product in products %}
   <div class="product-box">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
         <div class="front">
            <a href="{% url 'product-detail' product.slug %}">
               {% for image in product.images.all %}
                  {% if image.is_main %}
                     <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" class="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img" alt="">
                  {% endif %}
               {% endfor %}
            </a>
         </div>
      <div class="back">
         <a href="{% url 'product-detail' product.slug %}">
            {% for image in product.images.all %}
               {% if image.is_second_main %}
                  <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" class="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img" alt="">
               {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
         </a>
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```